# Preventing page breaks after lists

Tags: lists, page-breaking

How can I prevent a page break after an inner list when it is immediately followed by the end of an outer list?

Page breaks elsewhere within both lists should be permitted.

### MWE

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{lista}{%
  \list{}{}%
    \item\relax
}{%
    Prevent page break before here.
  \endlist
}
\newenvironment{listb}{%
  \list{}{}%
    \item\relax
}{%
  \endlist
}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{7.5cm plus 1cm}
\begin{lista}
  \begin{listb}
    \lipsum[4]
  \end{listb}
  Permit page break before here.
  \begin{listb}
    \lipsum[4]
  \end{listb}
\end{lista}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The inner list ends with a \par, and you cannot prevent a column break at a \par.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent a page break after an inner list when it is immediately followed by the end of an outer list, you can use the `\filbreak` command after the inner list and before the text that follows it. The `\filbreak` command encourages a page break at that point, preventing a break between the inner and outer lists. Here's an updated version of your MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{lista}{%
  \list{}{}%
    \item\relax
}{%
    Prevent page break before here.
  \endlist
}
\newenvironment{listb}{%
  \list{}{}%
    \item\relax
}{%
  \endlist\filbreak % Use \filbreak to prevent a page break after the inner list
}

\begin{document}
\vspace*{7.5cm plus 1cm}
\begin{lista}
  \begin{listb}
    \lipsum[4]
  \end{listb}
  \lipsum[1-2] % This text follows the inner list
\end{lista}
\end{document}
```

In this example, I added `\filbreak` after the `\endlist` command in the `listb` environment. This will help prevent a page break after the inner list when it is immediately followed by the end of the outer list.

[image]

Comment: Nice. I'm already doing the encourage/discourage option. It mostly works. But still fails sometimes. I can make `\filbreak` fail in my actual code. Probably because of other evil stuff I have happening before the end of the outer list.

Comment: @DavidPurton Hi, I don't know if I answered well and you like my answer. If you don't like it I can delete it. Hi

Comment: No don't delete it! This is a good answer. There are always multiple ways of doing things. I'll accept the answer if nothing better comes along. And I may be able to adjust other penalties to make \filbreak work

Comment: @DavidPurton Ok :-) Best regards.